# why is my withdraw function consuming infinite gas? it's a fairly simple function

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix, metamask

it's my first ever solidity contract and i can't figure out why my withdraw function is consuming infinite gas. when i compile the contract it gives a warning.

***Gas requirement of function Faucet.withdraw(uint256) high: infinite.***
 If the gas requirement of a function is higher than the block gas limit, it cannot be executed. Please avoid loops in your functions or actions that modify large areas of storage(this includes clearing or copying arrays in storage)"

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.11;

//Our First Contract is a Faucet
contract Faucet
{

//Deposits ethers
 function deposit(uint256 amount) payable public {
     require(msg.value == amount);
    // nothing to do!
}


//Give out ether to anyone who asks
function withdraw(uint256 withdraw_amount) public
{
    if(withdraw_amount <= address(this).balance)
    {
        //Send  the amount to address which requested it
        msg.sender.transfer(withdraw_amount);

    }

}

}
```

***Note: i have successfully deployed the contract but transactions are failing because they run out of gas. is it due to this warning ?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### UPDATE

If you want to send ether to a contract without calling any of its functions, you need to have a fallback function in that contract.

Add this function in the contract:

```
function () external payable {}
```

---

The code looks fine.

I also didn't encounter any problems when actually running your code.
Sometimes error messages are not accurate. Maybe you call withdraw with value?

You can use [remix](http://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=false&evmVersion=null&version=soljson-v0.5.11+commit.c082d0b4.js) to test it.

Comment: it gives a warning "Gas requirement of function Faucet.withdraw(uint256) high: infinite" i have deployed it successfully but whenever i send some ethers the transactions fails because the gas is all used, any hints what's wrong ? the contracts public key is "0x11aC92886904c05C5f4b82E1E031Dded356EB828" you can check for yourself i will update my question as well

Comment: check this out: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/contracts.html#fallback-function